# Searching Records From MySql Database Using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel 5.3 please help me to solve this issues. I need to filter the matching records from database by three parameters such as category, location, search string. this is my code:

```
$results = DB::table('ads')
                ->join('category', 'category.categoryID', '=', 'ads.categoryID')
                ->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.subCategoryID', '=', 'ads.subCategoryID')
                ->join('site_users', 'site_users.siteUserID', '=', 'ads.createdBy')
                ->join('location', 'location.locationID', '=', 'site_users.location')
                ->select('ads.*', 'category.categoryName', 'sub_categories.subCategoryName', 'location.locationName')
                ->where([
                    'ads.title', 'like', '%' . $data['q'] . '%',
                    'ads.isActive', 1
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    'location.locationName', 'like', '%' . $data['loc'] . '%',
                    'category.categoryName', 'like', '%' . $data['cat'] . '%'
                ])
                ->toSql();
        dd($results);
```

I debugged this code the result is :

```
"select `ads`.*, `category`.`categoryName`, `sub_categories`.`subCategoryName`, `location`.`locationName` from `ads` inner join `category` on `category`.`categoryID` = `ads`.`categoryID` inner join `sub_categories` on `sub_categories`.`subCategoryID` = `ads`.`subCategoryID` inner join `site_users` on `site_users`.`siteUserID` = `ads`.`createdBy` inner join `location` on `location`.`locationID` = `site_users`.`location` where (`0` = ? and `1` = ? and `2` = ? and `3` = ? and `4` = ?) or (`0` = ? and `1` = ? and `2` = ? and `3` = ? and `4` = ? and `5` = ?)"
```

> How can i do simple search function with multiple like operation
>   please give me a guide. Thanks

Comment: like conditions of this type happen to be database killers, but never mind that. Show the where clause that you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  $results = DB::table('ads')
            ->join('category', 'category.categoryID', '=', 'ads.categoryID')
            ->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.subCategoryID', '=', 'ads.subCategoryID')
            ->join('site_users', 'site_users.siteUserID', '=', 'ads.createdBy')
            ->join('location', 'location.locationID', '=', 'site_users.location')
            ->select('ads.*', 'category.categoryName', 'sub_categories.subCategoryName', 'location.locationName')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($data){
              $query->where('ads.title', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['q'].'%')
                   ->orWhere('location.locationName', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['loc'].'%')
                   ->orWhere('category.categoryName', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['cat'].'%')                        
            })
            ->where([
                'ads.isActive' => 1
            ])
            ->toSql();
```

Hope it helps

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: thnx bro it's working 

 ->where([
                'ads.isActive', 1
            ])

we need to change above code to 

  ->where('ads.isActive', 1)

Comment: Yeah you are right. That would have given syntax error. My bad.